# Hex signed 2's complement. Int to Hex convert

Tags: python

I have an example:

```
>>> print(hex(16).replace("0x", "00"))
0010
>>> print(hex(15).replace("0x", "00"))
00f
```

0010 its ok, but how to get 00 0F?

Comment: Are you trying to remove `0x`? Then you should do `.replace("0x", ""))`

Comment: no, it must be 00 at first

Comment: Is the width fixed? Always 4? What if the hex itself has 4 characters?

Comment: `print('{:04x}'.format(15), '{:04x}'.format(16))` or with `X` in `{:04X}` if you need `F` instead of `f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string formatting

```
print('{:04x}'.format(16))
print('{:04x}'.format(15)) 

number = 16
print('{:04x}'.format(number))
```

You can use `X` instead of `x` if you need `F` instead of `f`

---

Using `f-string`

```
number = 16
print(f'{number:04X}')
number = 15
print(f'{number:04X}')
```

---

With `hex()` you need `.upper()` to get `F` instead of `f`.

And use `zfill(4)` to add zeros.

```
print(hex(16).replace("0x", "00").upper().zfill(4))
print(hex(15).replace("0x", "00").upper().zfill(4))
```

or

```
print(hex(16)[2:].upper().zfill(4))
print(hex(15)[2:].upper().zfill(4))
```